# Why using the console can solve problem but in remix is can not?

Tags: solidity, remix

I have solved Preservation problem in ethernaut.
I do the same thing when using remix vs ethernaut's console but remix can not.

In remix I deploy my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

// Simple library contract to set the time
contract Attack {

    uint storedTime1;
    uint storedTime2;
  // stores a timestamp 
  uint storedTime;  

  constructor() {
    storedTime1 = 1;
    storedTime2 = 2;
  }

  function setTime(uint _time) public {
    storedTime = _time;
  }
}
```

Then I call `setFirstTime() function` with Attack contract's address. Finally, I call `setFirstTime() function` with my address, but nothing happen.

Then I find solution, but contract in solution the same above contract. But author of solution using ethernaut's console to solve. And then, I will try call `setFirstTime() function` with my address again but with ethernaut's console. it really did

My question is whether I did anything wrong when I did the remix?